# Trying to use a UUC multiple site certificate with IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, ssl, https, certificate

I've been trying unsuccessfully to use a UCC multiple site certificate to provide SSL to my subdomains (for example, I have the certificate set for www.example.com and I would like to bind it to sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com). These sites are all on the same ip.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to bind the certificate to the subdomains, strange behavior begins to happen. When attempting to use https with the subdomains, they redirect to the root site in some strange way (the URL reads https://sub1.example.com but displays the page https://www.example.com).

I've tried multiple solutions both through the IIS manager and the command line (appcmd in inetsrv), but nothing seems to be working. Any insight into the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IIS GUI manager is not able to configure these types of certificates properly, but command line should:

```
appcmd set site /site.name:{SITE NAME AS PER IIS GUI} /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='{IP ADDRESS TO BIND TO}:443:{HOSTHEADER OF WEBSITE}']
```

http://sslnews.blogspot.com/2010/11/requiring-multi-domains-to-wildcard-ssl.html

Comment: Unfortunately this approach won't work (I've tried). For a wildcard certificate this seems to be valid, but with UCC I still get the behavior described above.

Comment: Turns out I had to use a wildcard certificate rather than a UCC to do what I wanted. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I got Sean's answer to work! There are gotchas, however. First, set up an HTTPS binding on one of your sites without a host header. Specify your UCC certificate there. Then, follow Sean's instructions for each site that will be sharing the IP and cert, but varying by host header name. It will automatically use the right cert. That's gotcha number 1. Gotcha number 2 is never to edit these bindings in the UI or you will break them. Final note, be in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 if you are in 64-bit windows.